# Get Stored Proc Schema name in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to get the schema name string of a stored proc inside the stored proc itself. I don't know if it's possible because I didn't find any information about it.

Exemple :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `exemple` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `exemple`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE schema_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;
  SELECT GET_STORED_PROC_SCHEMA_NAME FROM STORED_PROC_INFO INTO schema_name;  
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe it would be good to describe what are you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I will insert this name in a table. The same stored proc will be executed on different schema and the result will be merged into the same table but with a column that indicate the schema name. I don't want extra parameter for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to do that, use the DATABASE() function.